# How can I ensure that GCP service accounts do not have Admin privileges?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, admin, identity, policy

I would like to ensure that Google Cloud Platform service accounts do not have Admin privileges.

Furthermore, I would like to prevent users from creating service accounts with admin privileges, or adding admin rights to existing service accounts.

Do you know of a method to ensure this via Policies?

Comment: You can create a group and add these people to the group, and limit scope of them with a specific policy. Also, in IAM, "Disable automatic IAM leases for standard service accounts"

Comment: Do you have an organization?

Comment: Yes I have an organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use granular permission depending on [what users needs to do](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview).

It is possible to limit the resources and even using those granular permissions you can create a custom role based of compute admin, and just removing all the permissions that follow the syntax "*.*.setIamPolicy". i.e.

```
compute.instances.setIamPolicy
compute.licenses.setIamPolicy
compute.machineImages.setIamPolicy
compute.licenseCodes.setIamPolicy
```

This can limit the users to set IAM bindings, but It is limited in general, for users, not just service accounts. Use for only SA's it's not possible.

I recommend you to follow up, the IAM [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations), so you can better manage your security, if needed, you can create [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests), to support [IAM conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#syntax_overview) role bindings.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) which can be done at the project or organization level. Add permission(s) to your created custom role.

Also, [IAM policies](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#policy-overview) will lets you control who (users) has what (roles) permission to which resources by setting IAM policies. (user account or service account, with a role).
After modifying the policy grant the desired roles and  call setIamPolicy() to make the updates.